# How do i query for user purchases When App Starts - Play Billing 1.0

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, play-billing-library

Here is my Billing Manager

```
public class BillingManager implements PurchasesUpdatedListener {
    private BillingClient mBillingClient;
    private Activity mActivity;

    public BillingManager(Activity activity) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mBillingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(mActivity).setListener(this).build();
        startServiceConnectionIfNeeded(null);
    }

    private void startServiceConnectionIfNeeded(final Runnable executeOnSuccess) {
        if (mBillingClient.isReady()) {
            if (executeOnSuccess != null) {
                executeOnSuccess.run();
            }
        } else {
            mBillingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onBillingSetupFinished(@BillingClient.BillingResponse int billingResponse) {
                    if (billingResponse == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "onBillingSetupFinished() response: " + billingResponse);
                        if (executeOnSuccess != null) {
                            executeOnSuccess.run();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "onBillingSetupFinished() error code: " + billingResponse);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                    Log.w(TAG, "onBillingServiceDisconnected()");
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

The Listener below only gets executed when am done with google play library

```
@Override
    public void onPurchasesUpdated(int responseCode, @Nullable List<Purchase> purchases) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPurchasesUpdated: ResponseCode = "+ responseCode);
        Log.d(TAG, "onPurchasesUpdated: Purchase = "+purchases);
        if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK && purchases != null) {
                //if user purchased something
        } else if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.USER_CANCELED) {
            // Handle an error caused by a user cancelling the purchase flow.
        } else {
            // Handle any other error codes.
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Just inside your activity's onCreate or even better onResume (this will prevent potential problems with lost purchases when switching between apps) in addition to successful onBillingSetupFinished callback.

For all similar questions, please check the latest [TrivialDrive_v2](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/tree/master/TrivialDrive_v2).

E.g. queryPurchase is triggered [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/blob/master/TrivialDrive_v2/shared-module/src/main/java/com/example/billingmodule/BaseGamePlayActivity.java#L160) and [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/blob/master/TrivialDrive_v2/shared-module/src/main/java/com/example/billingmodule/billing/BillingManager.java#L116) there.

Comment: Thanks, i now get it. `BillingClient.queryPurchases()` did the trick

Comment: Then it would be great if you accept my answer to help people with a similar question.